# Improving Flux architecture by reducing unnecessary code

Tags: javascript, reactjs, flux

In our codebase, we have recently migrated a lot of React components to a pure flux architecture. Thus, our data flow looks almost exactly like this image provided by the Facebook team:
[image: Flux data flow]
<sub>(source: [github.io](https://facebook.github.io/flux/img/flux-simple-f8-diagram-explained-1300w.png))</sub>

One issue we're running into is that there's a lot of boilerplate code required to make a call to the server and get a result. The process is as follows:

1. View propagates an action called something like `GET_DATA_FROM_SERVER` to an action creator (let's say called `ViewActionCreator`).
2. `ViewActionCreator` dispatches this action, which has no payload in most cases, and then calls `api.retrieveData`
3. Upon receiving data from the server, `api.retrieveData` dispatches an action, in this case called `SERVER_DATA_RECEIVED` with the retrieved data as the payload.
4. Stores respond to the two actions dispatched. However, in most cases stores only do something for the second action (`SERVER_DATA_RECEIVED`), since we've found that optimistic view updates are, with a few exceptions like logging in, not usually required or very helpful.

Hence, my question is, is there any reason why we shouldn't have views call `api`'s methods directly, and have those api methods dispatch actions only upon data reception?

Another related issue we're running into results from the use of constants, generated using https://github.com/STRML/keyMirror. We repeatedly run into an error where we forget to add a constant used in an action creator and store to our constants file, but this doesn't manifest until runtime, since our stores use switch statements to test which action they're receiving from the dispatcher, and when we use a constant that's undefined, this simply percolates down to the end of the switch statement.

Comment: Quick question - would one of the flux implementations help here? I know both marty and reflux have a lot of things to remove boilerplate like removing/reducing use of constants.

Comment: Potentially. We initially tried to avoid using any pre-packaged flux implementations because we wanted to avoid being dependent on their api updates in addition to the ones upon which we are already dependent (react-router, React itself). We already use the facebook dispatcher and, based on the tutorial, this seemed to be enough.

Perhaps we should reevaluate though. I can take a look myself, but, out of curiosity, do you know how difficult it would be to move from our own flux implementation to something like reflux?

Comment: Depends on the size of your application, of course, but I'd imagine it'd be a fair bit of work. But it could be worth seeking out other minimal implementations that are just syntactic sugar, since I have the feeling you're going to end up reinventing the wheel otherwise!

Comment: Makes sense. Any recommendations?

Comment: Flux is just a pattern (and not necessarily a good fit for every app or even every programmer). You can have a look at some of the options here as alternatives: https://github.com/facebook/react/wiki/Complementary-Tools#model-management There are also alternative ways of structuring data that aren't flux, for example: https://github.com/omniscientjs/omniscient (and if you look around, you'll find others).

Comment: Some abstractions could help too—for example, instead of using a big switch statement, use a JS object or a function to register action types to handlers. When you see null/undefined as the action type, you can throw an error much earlier.